# Tomcat7: Issue with multiple path in shared.loader

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have 4 web app which has their own properties and can be deployed successfully in tomcat but only one at a time when I am mentioning the property path in shared.loader property of tomcat server in Catalina.properties file.

However, when I am deploying the 4 web apps together with 4 paths in shared.loader with comma separated then it's getting failed. The reason, tomcat is only picking the first path mentioned in the shared.loader but not the next three.

So is there anyway I can mention all four paths in the class loader of tomcat7. I cannot club all the property into a single folder since in four paths there are some property files with the same name and also there are some properties in the property file which have same keys for all four web apps but a different value in respective property path.

Comment: How about to make 4 installations of tomcat each with its own shared.path

Comment: @ScaryWombat That i did and it worked perfectly but i want to have only one tomcat and all 4 apps running on the same.

Comment: There is one solution but with the code change in webapp [link](https://coderanch.com/t/86875/put-configurations-files-war-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two directories app1 and app2 in a common directory, eg. C:\myConfig\app1 and C:\myConfig\app2.

Put config.properties inside app1 and another config.properties inside app2.

Then create a file ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default with the contents:

```
<Context>
  <Parameter name="myConfigDirectory" value="C:/myConfig" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

The parameter myConfigDirectory will be available to all the applications on the host. It is better to create this parameter in context.xml.default rather than in server.xml, because the file can be changed later without restarting tomcat.

In the applicationContext.xml inside war you can access config.properties using the SpEL expression: "#{contextParameters.myConfigDirectory + servletContext.contextPath}/config.properties", so for example you can write:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="file:#{contextParameters.myConfigDirectory + servletContext.contextPath}/config.properties" />
</bean>
```

The expression will get expanded to C:/myConfig/app1 for application with contextPath /app1, and C:/myConfig/app2 for application with contextPath /app2. This will make the applications access the config.properties file based on their contextPath.

Reference : https://coderanch.com/t/86875/put-configurations-files-war-file